# stop input breaking out of container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have some pre-input on my forms and I want the input field to expand to the end of the container div. The problem is the input field seems to expand past the container div due to the length of the pre-input text.

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
}
.input-field {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.input-field .addon {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.input-field input {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field:hover {
  border: 1px solid #05c9f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-field">
    <span class="addon">some preinput</span>
    <input id="" type="text" name="" value="test text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgdErO

If you try the example code, you will note you can click the input box way outside where I want it to end.

Any thoughts on a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the flexbox layout.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}
.input-field {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.input-field .addon {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.input-field input {
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  resize: none;
  flex: 1;
}
.input-field:hover {
  border: 1px solid #05c9f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-field">
    <span class="addon">some preinput</span>
    <input id="" type="text" name="" value="test text" />
  </div>
</div>
<img src="//dummyimage.com/300x50">
```

Comment: Afraid not, as it's not padding, but the size of the content in the span.

Comment: @NaughtySquid Updated above with flexbox approach.

Comment: Oooo shiny, that fixes it perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NaughtySquid Tweaked a bit more now it should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Just decrease the input width from 100% to a lower value like 99.7% and that will do the trick:

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.input-field {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: bottom;
 background: #fff;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 99.7%;  
 min-width: 16px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.input-field .addon {
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 background: #f0f0f0;
}
.input-field input {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field:hover {border: 1px solid #05c9f0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-field">
    <span class="addon">some preinput</span>
    <input id="" type="text" name="" value="test text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While the problem is certainly due to the `width` of the input being 100% of the parent (which also covers the width of the span) this will unfortunately still have issues with responsiveness.

Comment: That does not fix it, at all. I can still select it outside of the box.

Comment: There are a lot of weak points in there, however the question is about a different issue @ObsidianAge

Comment: By selecting you mean when you hover over it? @NaughtySquid

Comment: I can select the input box way over to the right of where the content ends, your change does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the width like this! `width: calc(100% - 125px);` rather than set it to 100%

Comment: Why 125px? The pre-input will always be different lengths of course.

Comment: Actually this worked well for me. You'll have to determine what your pre-input length is, but yeah works like a charm.